# Order of $g$ is $n$, and $m \mid n$, if $h^m = g$. Prove order of $h$ is $mn$.

Tags: group-theory

Let $G$ be a group, $g,h \in G$ such that the order of $g$ is $n$. Suppose further that $m \in \mathbb{Z}^+$ such that $m \mid n$, and $h^m = g$. Prove that the order of $h$ is $mn$.

Obvious substitution gets us $(h^m)^n = e$. So I just need to show that $mn$ is the smallest number such that this is true. I know this has to be the case since $m | n$, but I can't seem to find a suitable justification.

Ive tried letting $|h| = a$ and then trying to show $mn = a$, via if $|<h>| = a$ then $|h^m| = \frac{a}{\gcd(m,a)} = n$ but Im not sure how to show $\gcd(m,a) = m$.

am I on the right track? Where do I go from here? Many thanks

Comment: $n|a$ and $m|n$ so $m|a$ so $\gcd(m,a)=m$.

Comment: @DerekHolt ahhh, thanks!